# update dropdown menu values depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<label>Sizes
  <select name="item_options[product_size]">
    <option value="s">small <span class="avail-inventory">10</span></option>
    <option value="m">medium <span class="avail-inventory">1</span></option>
    <option value="l">large <span class="avail-inventory">5</span></option>
    <option value="xl">extra large <span class="avail-inventory">10</span></option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>Quantity
  <select name="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

This is part of a shopping cart where the user can pick product option(size) and quantity. Since the quantity always varies, I would like the max quantity change on the fly depending on what product option the user chooses.

For instance if the user chooses size large the max number in quantity dropdown should also be only 5.

thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Also, people are more likely to help if you go back and accept some answers to your other questions: that would show you have some respect for the people who've helped you in the past.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep and object of your size quantities and update the select accordingly. Alternatively you could put both the size and quantity as a value of the select and then process the string e.g value="s|10" and then split the string, or use the data attribute of the html (or some other attribute)... Anyhow I think this is the best option below:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        sizes = {"m": 5, "s": 10, "l":2, "xl": 50}
        $(function(){
            $("#sizes").change(function(){
                index = $(this).val();

                var html = '<select name="quantity">';
                for (var i=0;i<sizes[index];i++){
                    html += "<option value=" + (i + 1) +">" + (i+1) + "</option>";

                }
                html +="</select>"

                $("#quantity").html(html);
            })
        })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Sizes
    <select id="sizes" name="item_options[product_size]">
                <option value="s">small <span class="avail-inventory">5</span></option>

                <option value="m">medium <span class="avail-inventory">10</span></option>

                <option value="l">large <span class="avail-inventory">2</span></option>

                <option value="xl">extra large <span class="avail-inventory">50</span></option>
            </select>
</label>
<br>
<label>Quantity</label>
  <span id="quantity">
  Please select size first
  </span>




    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

if you want to have a dropdown displayed here is how to do it:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        sizes = {"m": 5, "s": 10, "l":2, "xl": 50}
        $(function(){
            $("#sizes").change(function(){
                index = $(this).val();
                console.log(sizes[index])
                var html = '';
                for (var i=0;i<sizes[index];i++){
                    html += "<option value=" + (i + 1) +">" + (i+1) + "</option>";

                }


                $("#quantity").html(html);
                $("#quantity").removeAttr("disabled");
            })
        })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Sizes
    <select id="sizes" name="item_options[product_size]">
                <option value="s">small <span class="avail-inventory">5</span></option>

                <option value="m">medium <span class="avail-inventory">10</span></option>

                <option value="l">large <span class="avail-inventory">2</span></option>

                <option value="xl">extra large <span class="avail-inventory">50</span></option>
            </select>
</label>
<br>
<label>Quantity</label>
<select id="quantity" disabled=true>
<option>Please select size first</option></select>





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW - as far as I know you cannot retrieve html embedded in the option tag.

Comment: i took out the <span> tag within the <option>. All working nicely, thanks a lot!

Comment: i was playing around a bit and was wondering whether it would be possible to have a select dropdown already displaying when the dom loaded first time. ATM you ave to choose a value in the first dropdown to fire the javascript and set the proper values in the "quantity" dropdown.

Comment: how would that be possible? Can you post an exmaple or do I have to post a new question?

Comment: I added the version with the select box to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it appears you can't get the text() or html() from any tags in an `<option>`.  I changed the text inside the options a bit so that I could retrieve the value from the Option tag as a string and just did a split.

http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/hqLPp/

```
<option value="s">small - 10</option>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productSize").change(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var avail = me.find("option:selected").html().split("-")[1].trim();

        $("#quantity option").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        for(var i=1; i<= avail; i++) {
            $("#quantity").append("<option>"+i+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nice work the fiddle example does not work though in safari 4

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the script...I can't get anything with Jquery to run in any Safari browser.  Other frameworks are fine but as soon as I add jquery it no longer works.  Have you tried this outside of JSFiddle?  It works fine in Safari for me that way.